# Angular 7 routerLink directive warning 'Navigation triggered outside Angular zone'

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular7, angular-routerlink

I am struggling with Angular framework to get my application run smoothly, but I can't resolve an issue with routing. 
I have a top level `AppComponent` and `app-routing.module.ts` which manage the navigation via my custom `SlideMenuComponent`. My simplified html template of `AppComponent`:

```
<app-slide-menu [buttons]="menuButtons"></app-slide-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My `SlideMenuComponent` has the following html as its core:

```
<nav><div *ngFor="let button of buttons">
    <a routerLink="{{button.routerLink}}"
    >{{button.name}}</a>
</div></nav>
```

A user can navigate to `'/courses'` through this slide menu, which is supervised by `CoursesComponent` that paginates links to a particular `CourseComponent`s that are retrieved from the server. These components reside in their own `courses.module.ts` module whith their own `courses-routing.module.ts`. But when I click any of those links I get `Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?` console warning, `ngOnInit()` is not called for openned `CourseCompontent`, and it doesn't update untill I click any of the buttons on the page. I had this issue when manually navigating via `router.navigate()` that was resolved by forwarding this task to `NgZone.runTask(router.navigate())`, but why does this happen with `anchor` tags and `routerLink` direcrives?
Here is my `CoursesComponent` code excerpt:

```
<nav><ul>
        <li *ngFor="let course of api.data | paginate: {
            currentPage: currentPage, itemsPerPage: limit, totalItems: api.total
        }">
           <a
               [routerLink]="course._id"
               [queryParams]="{ page: '1', limit: '5' }"
           >
            {{course.name}} ({{course.description}})
           </a>
        </li>
</ul></nav>
```

A gif to demonstrate the issue:

> [image]

Comment: Can you try this code <nav><div *ngFor="let button of buttons">
    <a [routerLink]="[button.routerLink]"
    >{{button.name}}</a>
</div></nav>

Comment: @Suresh Sorry, maybe it is a bit misleading, but this code works fine, its my slide menu links, though I tried to change its interpolation type but nothing effectively changes. The issue arises when I click `<a
               [routerLink]="course._id"
               [queryParams]="{ page: '1', limit: '5' }"
           >
            {{course.name}} ({{course.description}})
           </a>`

Comment: RouteLink should be defined in [] bracket. [routerLink]="[course._id]".

Comment: @Suresh Tried, but no changes. Indeed routerLink may be just a string, not an array of paths

Comment: instead of routerlink, can you try caling click function and use navigateByURL as one option1 or instead of relative path, try to give absolute path '/courses/id'

Comment: @Suresh yeah, I may use it as a workaround, but **why** does this happen?

Comment: did you tried absolute path? whether it works?

Comment: @Suresh I tried [routerLink]="['/courses', course._id]" But it didn't help

Comment: might be isuue with anchor tag it seems. if you use anchor, we need to use click event.

Comment: Strange issue. Can you show the paginate pipe and how you resolve `api.data`?

Comment: @PierreDuc Here is a [gist of my component](https://gist.github.com/Veetaha/7d2ff2f860847142c47adc393fd4030f#file-courses-component-ts-LC53) anchored to function where I get courses from the server. Paginate pipe is from [ngx-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination) npm module

Answer (score 40):

It seens a bug, try this as an workaround

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private router: Router) {}

public navigate(commands: any[]): void {
    this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(commands)).then();
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks. any problems to be expected by this solution?

Comment: Thanks calebeaires. It works also for my case. I my case, it happened while navigating into Angular7 route from angularJs in a Angular7 & AngularJs hybird upgrade app.

Comment: This give me "ngZone is not defined"

Comment: @VincentGuyard, add this to your imports: import { Component, OnInit, ..., NgZone } from '@angular/core';

Comment: There could be multiple comportment in the application, do i need to put given code in all those components ?

Comment: For me I'm using FCM push notification in an Ionic chat app I built.  When the user gets the notification they click the icon and the app opens but it doesn't take them to the specified page.  I tried using this method to no avail.

Comment: Workaround works but feels like a hack and I can't figure what cause it.

Answer (score 6):

We had encountered this bug when we were navigating somewhere in our solution.

In our sidebar component we use on-push change detection and we have had one `this.ref.detectChanges()` when routing occured (change of parameters), which somehow broke routing (possibly kicking parallel running resolvers out of ngZone or something similar).
After changing this to the anyway preferred `this.ref.markForCheck()` this bug didn't appear again.
I'm happy we didn't need a workaround, weird behavior though..

Hope this helps anyone having the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Since there is no accepted answer, and since I found, using Angular 8, the top ranked answer does not quite work, and needs a little more explanation, I have the following to add:

My specific issue was with ag-grid, but I suspect any place where a component is injected, within an *ngFor or otherwise, can potentially cause this problem. This is very close to the previous answer, but instead declares a string parameter into the navigate function and then calls navigateByUrl instead of navigate.

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  template: `<tag (click)="navigate(path)">clickable text</tag>`
})

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private router: Router) { }

public navigate(path: string): void {
  this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl(path)).then();
}
```

Your mileage may vary, but this worked beautifully for me.

Comment: I'm trying this in my Ionic 4 (Angular) app when opening a push notification but is not making any result, still throwing the same warning and keeps stuck in the main page, any idea??

Comment: @HamletMinjares - No ideas. Are you sure you are following this pattern exactly? The (click) event must call the component's navigate function as shown; it cannot use routerLink any longer. Other than that, I would think this would work fine in Ionic. I can't see why that would make a difference, but I don't have a lot of experience with Ioninc.

Comment: I apologize; I was using a guard class to validate before call this method and didn't noticed that this guard was redirecting without ng zone. Just after I correted that, it worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: your answer helped me with my issue. despite using angular 10 instead of 8, it worked perfectly

Comment: Same issue with me also seems to be related to ag-grid rendering a template. I may do this as a temporary workaround, but I'd really like to get it working consistently with [routerLink] because I'd like it to be a true link that can be opened in another tab if the user chooses to.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error was because of a part of the code running outside the NgZone. After which we had a `this.ref.detectChanges()` running to detect changes. The changes detected would change the DOM and put `<a [routerLink]="..."></a>`. This use to break the routing.
Solution : We ran the part of code outside NgZone inside NgZone but using `this.ngZone.run` . This way we did not have to use `ref.detectChanged()` as the changed(RxJS Subject subscribe) were in NgZone. This solved the routing issue.

Hope this helps anyone having the same issue.

Comment: thanks! save me lot's of debugging hours

Answer (score -1):

Working Example - Refer this

```
 public backButtonSubscription;
      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        let self = this;
        this.backButtonSubscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
          console.log("back preseed \n \n");
    
          self._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              self.Router.navigateByUrl("/stock-management");
            }, 100);
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: OP is using routerLink, this is a copy-paste from another of your answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68415119/3294944